# Finding UK record(s) of British great-grandfather with children born in Japan during 1890s?

Tags: 19th-century, united-kingdom, japan

My great-grandfather is British.

He was in Japan during the 1890s working with trade.

His wife's name is Kogiku.

The couple had three sons.

My great-grandfather is thought to have returned to Britain in 1899.

I have studied his name and am now researching one candidate.

His name is C.Z.Ede. He was working at Jardine Matheson. Some researchers suggest that C.Z.Ede is not British which would mean that he is not my great-grandfather.

The above is what I have learned from the records of Kobe, Japan.

Is there a way to find C.Z.Ede in the UK?

Comment: To acknowledge the efforts that two people have put into answering this question I think that you should upvote both (you may have already) and Accept (click the big green tick) the one which has helped you the most.  From the two answers it would seem that both included records of C.Z.Ede that were found in the U.K. which would appear to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

There was Cecil Zohrab Ede (birth registered in Mar-Jun 1863, Altrincham, reference 8a 167). He appears to have died in China - see http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C1948323 for details of his probate. This might give you more information. It looks like C Z Ede should appear at about line 254 on this page: http://zohrabfamily.atwebpages.com/ztbltre3.html (I think he was the son of Frederick Charles Ede). This tree takes you back to the Zohrab line in Persia.....

---

"England and Wales, Birth Registration Index, 1837-2008," index, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:2616-19C : accessed 28 April 2015), Cecil Zohrab Ede, 1863; from "England & Wales Births, 1837-2006," database, findmypast (http://www.findmypast.com : 2012); citing Birth Registration, Altrincham, Cheshire, England, citing General Register Office, Southport, England.

Answer (score 2):

Familysearch at https://familysearch.org has a Cecil Zohrab EDE born in England christened at Bowdon, Cheshire on 21st June 1863. This Cecil is the son of Frederic & Helen Ede. The 1871 census (also at Familysearch) has the family together in the parish of Bowdon in Cheshire all are born in England except Frederic who lists his place of birth as Austria

---

"England, Cheshire Bishop's Transcripts, 1598-1900," index, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:NH66-7XX : accessed 28 April 2015), Cecil Zohrab Ede, 21 Jun 1863, Christening; citing item 1 p 130, Bowdon, Cheshire, England, Record Office, Chester; FHL microfilm 1,655,422.

"England and Wales Census, 1871," index and images, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:VB6B-BD9 : accessed 28 April 2015), Cecil Z Ede in household of Frederick C Ede, Bowdon, Cheshire, England; from "1871 England, Scotland and Wales census," database and images, findmypast (http://www.findmypast.com : n.d.); citing PRO RG 10, folio 143, p. 1, Altrincham registration district, Altrincham subdistrict, ED 11, household 2, The National Archives, Kew, Surrey; FHL microfilm 841,872.