# Finding descendants and potential relatives of immigrant to USA from Spain through Cuba?

Tags: united-states, migration, spain, cuba

I am trying to find an almost certainly dead relative that emigrated from Spain to Cuba before finally moving to USA.

I have in my hands the complete name with Spanish conventions (name + 2 surnames) and will have the birth date in Spain (around 1920s).

I have a parallel investigation to get information about the emigration to Cuba and later on to USA.

What I am trying to do is to find details about this person, specially descendents and potential relatives. How can I achieve this without direct contact with the person?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  It seems like you may already be aware on our privacy policy concerning people born during the past 100 years, who cannot be proven deceased, but in case you are not, then it can be found in the [help/on-topic].  There is some extra information that I think you may be able to provide which would be helpful to any potential answerers.  Are you able to provide the year they were born in Spain, the years (or estimates) of arriving and departing Cuba, and the year or estimate of arrival in the US?

Comment: I am investigating in parallel, everything I have is provided... I will update as soon as I have something in hands. Thanks for the hint, I already took a tour.

Comment: At the moment there is no question mark in the body of your question that makes it hard to be sure what you are asking.  Are you asking how to find this potentially living person (in the flesh), or are you asking how to find a particular fact about their life, or something else?

Comment: THanks, I tried to update it. Just looking how can I investigate and track about the person.

Comment: I have concerns about your question because it now seems to be about trying to connect with multiple living people.  I'll hold off on casting my binding moderator vote on this, for now, to give others a chance to weigh in.  Some discussion has been had about questions like this one at http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1747/seeking-possibly-living-individuals-clarity-required

Comment: Well my question is more about getting information about this potentially dead person, with the intention to expand my recent geneology chart. My main concern is knowing how to locate this person. Main difficulty is knowing which records available in Cuba or USA can be used and how/which informaitno is needed

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  I think part of the difficulty here is that there is no focused research question, apart from asking how to find the descendants of this person, which is off-topic.

Comment: Although it may look very unlike a duplicate at first, I nevertheless think that it is because [this answer](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/9154/19) applies equally to both questions.  Wanting to contact living relatives is a sensible thing to do when conducting G&FH research, but our privacy policy prevents us from being able to assist with such questions here.  Remember that your potential relatives may not want to be contacted or found, and any wishes they may have about their privacy need to be respected.