# Proving identity of Japanese great grandfather when no marriage record?

Tags: 19th-century, records, marriage-records, japan

I am trying to prove who my great-grandfather is. I investigated many records (Kobe Directory, Japanese "koseki"), and even DNA testing, but I'm still not sure.

In the Japanese koseki, the name Mr Ede was not included because the names of foreigners weren't record in the old days. I have searched the Kobe Directory from 1888 to 1900, because my great-grandmother had three babies from 1893 to 1899. She had three sons. The youngest child is my grandfather. His brothers knew their father, but my grandfather didn't. And after my grandfather was born on Sep 25, 1899, his family became poor.

Then I think my great-grandfather left at 1899 or 1900. So I searched the Kobe Directory from 1888 to 1900. There I found thee possible candidates. One of them is C.Z. Ede. The records of the two other men exist. Each had a wife, and I found their wives' names. So Cecil Zohrab Ede became the most likely candidate for being my great-grandfather.

My problem is, I don't know what to do from here. I have tried DNA testing. I contacted a member of Zohrab family. He said C.Z.Ede is my great-grandfather, and that the circumstantial evidence is satisfied. The boarding list and inheritance document suggest C.Z.Ede is my great-grandfather. The member of Zohrab family said "I want to put you onto family-tree.", but I said "Please wait till I am convinced he is my great-grandfather".

However, I am not yet convinced that C.Z. Ede is my great-grandfather. I want to know what I need to do to find proof. I think there may be a record where C.Z.Ede and Kogiku (my great-grandmother) can be shown to be married. I looked for marriage record, but records of church were burned by air raids.

Do you have any suggestions for where I might find proof of their marriage in the absence of a marriage record?

Comment: So that we can align your questions with our focussed Q&A format, and work out which have been answered and which have not, I strongly encourage you to look back at [your first question](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/8117/finding-uk-records-of-british-great-grandfather-with-children-born-in-japan-du) which has two answers, both of which I think are acceptable but neither of which you have yet accepted.  It is the accepting (and upvoting) of answers that encourages people to keep providing them.  This does not mean that you should hurry to accept but to think carefully about Q&A.

Comment: I think we should keep this question focussed on finding any paper records related to the marriage (and not be distracted into the DNA evidence that is in a separate question).