# Seeking candidates for British ancestor who fathered children in Kobe (Japan) during 1890s?

Tags: 19th-century, united-kingdom, japan, 1890s

I have been considering a Mr C.Z. Ede to be the best candidate for my British great-grandfather who fathered children in Japan.

However, during the 1890s, there were many foreigners living in Kobe. So, I am now looking for people with similar backgrounds, as well as C.Z. Ede. The Japan Directory lists foreigners and it has been published every year from around 1870 until the early 1900s. I was looking for a person who lived in Kobe in that document.

The oldest brother of my grandfather was born in January 1893. The youngest of the three brothers was born in September 1899. I have heard that my grandfather did not know his father. So, I think he was in Kobe great from before 1892 until 1899. Roster principle person who was in January of that year is published. Persons listed in list 1900 and I thought that there is a possibility. However, great-grandmother is in the householder on behalf of her father's poor health in 1902. So, I think that is less likely to was in Japan is great-grandfather until 1902.

I think the person who left Japan in 1899 to 1901 in the person who was in Japan in January 1899 is to be a candidate of great-grandfather.

I have extracted a person where there is the possibility in addition to CZEde from its roster.

That is the next name. CZEde thought it was British because the company was the UK system. However, this time candidates, article does not clearly poor nationality. In addition, even obscure description, even I do not know whether individual or otherwise.

Until 1899, but was in Japan, people or organization that was not in Japan in 1900.

1. Blackwell.A.Herbert
2. Groppi .A
3. Mahlmann Capt j, j.,(I think that it is not person )
4. Morris.A

But it was in 1900 in Japan. After that, I could not be investigated in the study expires, the person or organization.

1. Hall.J
2. Kerr.w.a  (I think that it is not a British)
3. Noёl E.W.H.H (I think that it is not a British)
4. weale, A.G.M ,. cornes & co(I think that it is organization )

The person on the top and C.Z. Ede remained as a candidate. I think one of these eight (plus C.Z. Ede) must be my great-grandfather. But it is difficult to identify this new candidate of nationality. Because, CZEde was, can be identified because it was found a company that was working, I do not know only the name of the upcoming candidate.

---

Related questions:

- [Proving identity of Japanese great grandfather when no marriage record?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9418/proving-identity-of-japanese-great-grandfather-when-no-marriage-record)
- [Finding UK record(s) of British great-grandfather with children born in Japan during 1890s?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/8117/finding-uk-records-of-british-great-grandfather-with-children-born-in-japan-du)

Comment: You may have mentioned this somewhere before, but are their birth certificates/records for any of the brothers born during the 1890s and, if so, what do they say about their father?  Be sure to use the **edit** button to clarify this in your question.

Answer (score 2):

From: http://www.archerfamily.org.uk/family/weale.htm

**Arthur George Morey [WEALE]**, partner in the firm of Cornes & Co., Japan 1897-1911, of Impington Hall, Cambridgeshire and Echo Pit Lodge, Warwick’s Bench, Guildford, b. 8 Nov 1865 in Strawberry Vale, Twickenham, bapt 24 Dec 1865 at Old Church, Teddington, d. 22 Sep 1940 in Guildford (Will dated 21 Dec 1931 and proved 8 Jan 1941) having had issue, probably by Eizuka Masa of 1496 Nakamura, Yokohama, Japan:

1. Eric Cuthbert Sydney [WEALE], M.A., Squadron Leader, R.A.F., of 8 Aldeburgh Close, Emmer Green, Reading, b. 9 Jul 1904, educ Rugby, Pembroke College, Cambridge, m. Blanche Falzon (née Sant Manduca), M.B.E., of Malta, formerly wife of Alexander Chancellor. She d. 16 Dec 1986 and he d. 15 Dec 1989 having had issue: 2 sons and 1 dau.

**Arthur Herbert Blackwell**, of the firm Crosse and Blackwell (famous British food company) was listed as a founder member of the Freemasons' Lodge in Yokohama but appears to have died in Australia in 1888. (http://skirret.com/papers/lodge640/history/640-his-4.html) (trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/6895127)

**John James Mahlmann:** his memoirs available in full in English here: http://www.ebooksread.com/authors-eng/john-j-mahlmann/reminiscences-of-an-ancient-mariner-ala.shtml. Appears he was Australian: http://sydney.edu.au/arts/research_projects/austtravel/view_author.php?author=Mahlmann,%20John%20James

Answer (score 1):

Keeping this second answer separate, in case any further information comes to light about the men named in the original question.

The article, "Intergroup Marriage in a Conflicted Milieu: Marriage between Japanese and Non-Japanese in the Yokohama Treaty Port" by Chester Proshan for the International Academic Forum (PDF at https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=36&ved=0CO8BEBYwI2oVChMIlKvmj--SxwIVg24UCh061Qd1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fiafor.org%2Farchives%2Foffprints%2Facss2011-offprints%2FACSS2011_0090.pdf&ei=qX3CVdSyNoPdUbqqn6gH&usg=AFQjCNHq6vizAmUxia3vFae45vLyFdF3qg&sig2=Xjs7vT0TuzE7DplGWRHDoA) shows just how complicated the situation was in Japan at the end of the 19th Century. It was extremely easy for foreigners to take up with Japanese women. The author was able to find examples of documented relationships. Perhaps @Akira may wish to contact him?

Answer (score 1):

I examined the eight people that I wrote about in my question and concluded that none of them are my ancestor.

I have examined all the records of foreigners in the 1890s and only Cecil Zohrab Ede remains as my possible ancestor.

Circumstantial evidence we have suggests that he is my great-grandfather with little chance of there being a mistake.

However, we want even more direct evidence, so now we are trying to locate descendants of his mother.

Comment: I've edited your answer quite heavily because I think I understand what you are saying.  I also removed the questions at the end because an answer will normally consist of statements rather than more questions.